# Reading multiple ternary operator conditions

Tags: javascript

I've come across the following code:

```
      if (proto.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
         !(specPolicy === SpecPolicy.DEFINE_MANY || specPolicy === SpecPolicy.DEFINE_MANY_MERGED) ? process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? invariant(false, 'ReactClassInterface: You are attempting to define ' + '`%s` on your component more than once. This conflict may be due ' + 'to a mixin.', name) : invariant(false) : undefined;
      }
```

How do you read the ternary operator in line 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to format an indent your code for better understanding.

```
if (proto.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    !(
        specPolicy === SpecPolicy.DEFINE_MANY //1
        ||
        specPolicy === SpecPolicy.DEFINE_MANY_MERGED //1
    ) ?
        process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? //2
            invariant(false, 'ReactClassInterface: You are attempting to define ' + '`%s` on your component more than once. This conflict may be due ' + 'to a mixin.', name) :
            invariant(false)//3
        : undefined;//4
}
```

(1) If `specPolicy` is neither `SpecPolicy.DEFINE_MANY` nor `SpecPolicy.DEFINE_MANY_MERGED`, then check if `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not "production". 
(2) If so then call `invariant(false, 'Re....`, else call (3)`invariant(false)`.
If (1) is true return `undefined` (4).

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments says, you should probably convert this to a traditional if-else tree for readability/sanity. However, it would read like this (I haven't written it out verbatim for brevity's sake, but you get the gist):

```
if (!conditionOne) {
    if (conditionTwo) {
        return invariant(false, 'ReactClass...', name);   
    }
    else {
        return invariant(false);
    }
}
else {
   return undefined;
}
```

I figured answering this by converting to the code to an if-else tree may help you understand it a little easier :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ternary operators. See if this way of formating it helps:

```
!(specPolicy === SpecPolicy.DEFINE_MANY || specPolicy === SpecPolicy.DEFINE_MANY_MERGED) ? 
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 
        invariant(false, 'ReactClassInterface: You are attempting to define ' + '`%s` on your component more than once. This conflict may be due ' + 'to a mixin.', name) : 
        invariant(false) : 
    undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use proper indents. The most inner ternary is grouped together like

```
condition1 ? condition2 ? value1 : value2 : value3
```

is the same as

```
condition1 ? (condition2 ? value1 : value2) : value3
```

With your code;

```
!(specPolicy === SpecPolicy.DEFINE_MANY || specPolicy === SpecPolicy.DEFINE_MANY_MERGED) ? 
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 
        invariant(false, 'ReactClassInterface: You are attempting to define ' + '`%s` on your component more than once. This conflict may be due ' + 'to a mixin.', name) :
        invariant(false) :
    undefined;
```